# infinite scroll in codeigniter using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello guys i have a simple problem i think:

I've created a blog in code igniter and this is how my code looks:

this is my home_page controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['posts'] = $this->Model_cats->getLivePosts(7);
        $data['cats'] = $this->Model_cats->getTopCategories(); 
        $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
        $data['main'] = 'public_home';
        $data['main2'] = 'public_home_loadpost';
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
```

and i use this jquery for loading:

```
$(window).scroll(function())
{
    if( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){
        $('div#loadMoreComments').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: "WHAT PAGE PUTHERE.php?lastComment=" + $(".postedComment:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
                if(html)
                {
                    $("#postedComments").append(html);
                    $('div#loadMoreComments').hide();

                }
                else
                {
                    $('div#loadMoreComments').replaceWith("Finished Loading the comments");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

i really don 't know what page i can put in my url in the jquery file... the page that will get more posts for me. help please

my view looks like this

```
<?php

    if ( count($posts) )
    {
        foreach ($posts as $key => $list)
        {
            echo "<div class='postedComment'>";
            echo '<h2>'.$list['title'].'</h2>';
            echo auto_typography( word_limiter($list['body'], 200) );
            echo anchor('welcome/post/'.$list['id'],'read more >>');
            echo "</div>";
        }

        echo '<br/><br/>';
    }

?>

<div id='loadMoreComments' style="display:none;">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another view in an controller. That view's url will be called by the ajax function and returns the data in JSON format back or whatever you want.

Here is an simple way to use ajax.

Example of an very simple ajax view (in an controller):

```
public function ajax_get_current_date_time() {
    die(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>The current date and time: <b id="current_time"></b></div>
```

Then in the front js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/controller/ajax_get_current_date_time",
    success: function(data){
        $('#current_time').html(data);
    }
});
```

For your situation you can better use JSON. Here's an example of your ajax call with JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/controller/ajax_get_post",
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'lastComment=' + $(".postedComment:last").attr("id"),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
        // trigger function that will transform the JSON data into HTML
        add_post(data);
    }
});
```

See the JSON part, the requested url must return JSON. More info about JSON: [click!](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/php/php-json-an-example-javascript-json-client-with-php-server/)